# Get OS in c++ win32 for all versions of win?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, operating-system

How to get the OS version for all windows, at least the name for win95,98,me,xp,vista,7?

Im using visual c++ 2010 and I want to include this feature in a pure win32 app.

Comment: Related: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/20/10013612.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GetVersionEx` 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It does say: `Minimum supported client: Windows 2000 Professional`

Comment: Pretty sure that API has been in Win32 API since Windows 95

Comment: Found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189249 @nico & @Paul Dixon, you are *absolutely* right. Sorry :) +1

Comment: I don't know why they revised all the MSDN documentation changing the "minimum supported client" voice to Windows 2000 Professional for all the "old" APIs. That's plain stupid, there was no need for that.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Probably some stupid corporate decision to piss off developers. :)

Comment: Yes, I too think that it's because of such thing. Fortunately, I've still got my MSDN 2003, with all the correct "Minimum supported" versions.

Comment: NOTE: GetVersionEx is not guaranteed to be around after Windows 8... It is replaced by the Version Helper API functions which don't actually return you a OS version number...arrg.

Comment: `GetVersionEx` is deprecated, and it will return 8 for any Windows higher than 8, unless you target a higher version in the manifest explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <lm.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

bool GetWinMajorMinorVersion(DWORD& major, DWORD& minor)
{
    bool bRetCode = false;
    LPBYTE pinfoRawData = 0;
    if (NERR_Success == NetWkstaGetInfo(NULL, 100, &pinfoRawData))
    {
        WKSTA_INFO_100* pworkstationInfo = (WKSTA_INFO_100*)pinfoRawData;
        major = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_major;
        minor = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_minor;
        ::NetApiBufferFree(pinfoRawData);
        bRetCode = true;
    }
    return bRetCode;
}


std::string GetWindowsVersionString()
{
    std::string     winver;
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osver;
    SYSTEM_INFO     sysInfo;
    typedef void(__stdcall *GETSYSTEMINFO) (LPSYSTEM_INFO);

    __pragma(warning(push))
    __pragma(warning(disable:4996))
    memset(&osver, 0, sizeof(osver));
    osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osver);
    GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO)&osver);
    __pragma(warning(pop))
    DWORD major = 0;
    DWORD minor = 0;
    if (GetWinMajorMinorVersion(major, minor))
    {
        osver.dwMajorVersion = major;
        osver.dwMinorVersion = minor;
    }
    else if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 2)
    {
        OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi;
        ULONGLONG cm = 0;
        cm = VerSetConditionMask(cm, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
        ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(osvi));
        osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
        osvi.dwMinorVersion = 3;
        if (VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_MINORVERSION, cm))
        {
            osver.dwMinorVersion = 3;
        }
    }

    GETSYSTEMINFO getSysInfo = (GETSYSTEMINFO)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "GetNativeSystemInfo");
    if (getSysInfo == NULL)  getSysInfo = ::GetSystemInfo;
    getSysInfo(&sysInfo);

    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 10 && osver.dwMinorVersion >= 0 && osver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows 10 Server";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 10 && osver.dwMinorVersion >= 0 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows 10";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 3 && osver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows Server 2012 R2";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 3 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows 8.1";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && osver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows Server 2012";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows 8";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 1 && osver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows Server 2008 R2";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 1 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows 7";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 0 && osver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows Server 2008";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 0 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  winver = "Windows Vista";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && osver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION
        &&  sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)  winver = "Windows XP x64";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 2)   winver = "Windows Server 2003";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 1)   winver = "Windows XP";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osver.dwMinorVersion == 0)   winver = "Windows 2000";
    if (osver.dwMajorVersion < 5)   winver = "unknown";

    if (osver.wServicePackMajor != 0)
    {
        std::string sp;
        char buf[128] = { 0 };
        sp = " Service Pack ";
        sprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), "%hd", osver.wServicePackMajor);
        sp.append(buf);
        winver += sp;
    }

    return winver;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Here is some code with Win 11 support. It won't work for server versions, but it is easy to implement add this feature (just another mapping for servers).

```
 // To Workaround Win 10 problem for User Mode VerifyVersionInfo
bool VerifyWindowsVersionInfo(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW versionInfo, ULONG typeMask, ULONGLONG conditionMask)
{
    HMODULE hMod = nullptr;
    if ((TRUE != ::GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, L"ntdll.dll", &hMod)) || !hMod)
        return false;

    typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* _RtlVerifyVersionInfo)(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW, ULONG, ULONGLONG);
    const auto RtlVerifyVersionInfo =
        reinterpret_cast<_RtlVerifyVersionInfo>(::GetProcAddress(hMod, "RtlVerifyVersionInfo"));

    if (!RtlVerifyVersionInfo)
        return false;

    return NT_SUCCESS(RtlVerifyVersionInfo(versionInfo, typeMask, conditionMask));
}

bool IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(int wMajorVersion, int wMinorVersion, int wBuildNumber, int wServicePackMajor)
{
    RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = { sizeof(osvi), 0, 0, 0, 0, {0}, 0, 0 };
    osvi.dwMajorVersion = wMajorVersion;
    osvi.dwMinorVersion = wMinorVersion;
    osvi.dwBuildNumber = wBuildNumber;
    osvi.wServicePackMajor = static_cast<WORD>(wServicePackMajor);

    DWORDLONG dwlConditionMask = 0;
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_BUILDNUMBER, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);

    return VerifyWindowsVersionInfo(&osvi,
        VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_BUILDNUMBER | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR,
        dwlConditionMask);

}

std::wstring GetVerbalOsVersion()
{
    // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx for details
    using OsMajorVersion = int;
    using OsMinorVersion = int;
    using OsBuildVersion = int;
    using OsServicePackMajorVersion = int;

    using VersionStrWithNumberPair =
        std::pair<std::wstring, std::tuple<OsMajorVersion, OsMinorVersion, OsBuildVersion, OsServicePackMajorVersion>>;


    const auto win11BuildNumber = 22000;

    const std::vector<VersionStrWithNumberPair> winVersionMapping = {
        {L"Windows 11 ",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), win11BuildNumber, 0)},
        {L"Windows 10 ", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), 0, 0)},

        {L"Windows 8.1", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), 0, 0)},
        {L"Windows 8 ", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), 0, 0)},

        {L"Windows 7  Service Pack 1", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 0, 1)},
        {L"Windows 7 ", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 0, 0)},

        {L"Windows Vista Service Pack 2",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 0, 2)},
        {L"Windows Vista Service Pack 1",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 0, 1)},
        {L"Windows Vista", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 0, 0)},

        {L"Windows XP  Service Pack 3",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 0, 3)},
        {L"Windows XP Service Pack 2",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 0, 2)},
        {L"Windows XP Service Pack 1",
         std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 0, 1)},
        {L"Windows XP ", std::make_tuple(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 0, 0)} };

    const auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(winVersionMapping),
        std::end(winVersionMapping),
        [](const VersionStrWithNumberPair& el)
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(std::get<0>(el.second),
                std::get<1>(el.second),
                std::get<2>(el.second),
                std::get<3>(el.second));
        });

    if (it == std::end(winVersionMapping))
        return L"Unknown windows version";

    return it->first;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the MSDN article **[Getting the System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429(VS.85).aspx)**

While the article only mentions currently supported Windows versions, see this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189249) for the numbers you'll see in the  OSVERSIONINFO structure for Win 95, 98 etc.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on why you need to know OS version:

- **To use certain feature that may not be available in older OS.** In this case I would strongly suggest checking if the API itself is available using [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) functions. Otherwise, I guess you can dynamically import [RtlGetVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlgetversion) from `ntdll.dll` and use it, but again, there're too many ways it can return inaccurate information (the ones that come to mind are compatibility mode and *API trampolines* that can be installed by malware, AVP, and even OS itself.)
- **For display purposes only.** (ex: in `About` window for your app, or to include it in your diagnostic event log, etc.) In this case a quick and easy *hack* is to read it as text from the System Registry:

[image]

*The downside of this approach though, is that the names and numbers can be localized for the end-user's system.*

Use the following key that is available since Windows XP:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

and its following `REG_SZ` (or string) values:

- `ProductName` = for OS name
- `CurrentVersion` = for OS version
- `BuildLab` = for full build number
- `BuildLabEx` = extended build number (available since Windows 7)
- `ReleaseId` = Release number (available since Windows 10)