# C++ Detect OS Version

Tags: c++, windows

I want to know how to detect the running OS using the C++ and which service pack installed

Comment: this should work on windows platform

Comment: added [windows] tag accordingly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get OS in c++ win32 for all versions of win?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877295/get-os-in-c-win32-for-all-versions-of-win)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows, see this example called [GetOSDisplayString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN, in which the use of **GetVersionEx** is demonstrated.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're writing unmanaged C++ using Win32? Look into the Win32 API [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is for Windows - use [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak37a69s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx