# Performing a conditional function based on windows OS

Tags: c++

I'm wondering on how I could achieve performing a conditional function based on what operating system I'm using, for example,

```
if ( operatingSystem == Windows7 )
{
   foo()
}
else if ( operatingSystem == WindowsXP )
{
   etc()
}
```

I am pretty sure predefined macros won't help me with this since you have to choose the OS macro before you compile, I want this program to be flexible and unfortunately preprocessor macros are the only answer I'm getting when I google it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: already answered here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877295/get-os-in-c-win32-for-all-versions-of-win][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877295/get-os-in-c-win32-for-all-versions-of-win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetVersionEx()`. Read [GetVersionEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [OSVERSIONINFOEX structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for details on how to interpret the data.